# Why Cassandra query not fetching data

Tags: cassandra, nosql

I have been modelling a column family. As of now the primary key is 
Primary Key((side,rundate),fund). So i am performing the following query

```
 select count(*) from cf_Summary 
 where side = 'Long'and rundate in ('2015-01-12 05:30:00','2015-01-13 05:30:00');
```

Above query is returning 1200. If i run below query then its returning 0 records.

```
select count(*) from cf_Summary 
where token(side,rundate)>= token('Long','2015-01-12 05:30:00') and token(side,rundate) <= token('Long','2015-01-13 05:30:00');
```

Token operator can be applied on last two partition columns as mentioned in datastax website.
http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/a-deep-look-to-the-cql-where-clause

Why am i getting the 0 count in second query. Side has two values Long and Short so i would like to perform the query sometime for long and sometime for short and sometime for both values in a date range. In the first query i can restrict the rundate but can query both long and shot. I know both row keys are stored on different rows.

Is it possible to perform

```
select count(*) from cf_valuationsummary_1 
where token(side,rundate)>= token('Long','2015-01-02 05:30:00') and token(side,rundate) <= token('Short','2015-01-03 05:30:00');
```

Coordinator node can query two node to get data but i want to perform single query from client application despite performance issues

Any lead??

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using different date strings in the two queries.

In the first query with the IN clause, you used date 01-12 and 01-13.

But in the token queries you are using dates 01-02 and 01-03.

So perhaps you don't have any rows for 01-02 and 01-03.

Other than that, the token queries look valid.

---

Update:

I did some more experiments.  I think this type of query may only work with the ByteOrderedPartitioner.  When using the Murmur3Partitioner the token values for a given partition key aren't ordered by the date string.  For example, with this data:

cqlsh:test> select * from cf_Summary;

```
 side  | rundate             | fund
-------+---------------------+------
 Short | 2015-01-13 05:30:00 |  HIJ
  Long | 2015-01-12 05:30:00 |  ABC
  Long | 2015-01-13 05:30:00 |  DEF
 Short | 2015-01-12 05:30:00 |  HIJ
```

We get token values like this:

cqlsh:test> select token(side,rundate) from cf_Summary;

```
 token(side, rundate)
----------------------
 -2522183250639624078
 -2064350486281951596
 1812183325578390943
 7832903641319907586
```

So you can see that the Short row with a higher date has a negative token value, while the earlier Short date has a positive token value.  So if I do a range query on those token values it finds zero rows.  For the Long rows it happened that the token value for the earlier date was negative and the later date was positive, so that finds the two Long rows.

cqlsh:test> select count(*) from cf_Summary  where token(side,rundate)>= token('Short','2015-01-12 05:30:00') and token(side,rundate) <= token('Short','2015-01-13 05:30:00');

### count

```
 0
```

cqlsh:test> select count(*) from cf_Summary  where token(side,rundate)>= token('Long','2015-01-12 05:30:00') and token(side,rundate) <= token('Long','2015-01-13 05:30:00');

### count

```
 2
```

So in general I don't think what you are trying to do will work since the token values don't directly correlate to your increasing dates.

Comment: i have edited the question. token query is not returning the data whereas IN query returning data

Comment: The first and second queries both work fine in my setup.  Could you show your table definition, which partitioner you are using, and what version of Cassandra you are using.

Comment: got your point. Is there any other way to query the data. I have time series data. Millions of trades per day. Most frequent query has rundate in the where clause. Trades can be queried in the date range so rundate has to be last column of the partition key. Side is first partition key in order to divide the one date data into two partition. Requirement is to query by Long side,Short side or both.

Comment: Well that's a different question so you might want to start a new question for  that.  C* is only good at range queries within a partition, so you need to set up tables to put the right data in a single partition.  You may need multiple tables with different views of the data to support all your queries.  If you want to do queries/analysis across multiple partitions, then you might need to look into pairing C* with spark.

Comment: Cassandra 2.2 allows IN operator to be used  with any column in the primary key that way above queries can be used. Waiting for C* 2.2 for production uses